# Using tidyr::separate_rows on multiple connected rows

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have some data that I scrubbed from an offline source using some text recognition software. It looks something like the data below, but less Elvish.

```
elvish_ring_holders_unclean <- tibble(
name=c("Gandalf", "Galadriel", "Elrond", "Cirdan\n\nGil-Galad"), 
city = c("Undying Lands","Lothlorien","Rivendell", "Mithlond\n\nLindon"), 
race = c("Maiar", "Elf", "Elf", "Elf\n\nElf"))
```

The problem for both datasets is that certain rows have been concatenated together with spaces. What I would prefer is something like the data below with each observation having its own row

```
elvish_ring_holders <- tibble(
name=c("Gandalf", "Galadriel", "Elrond", "Cirdan","Gil-Galad"), 
city = c("Undying Lands","Lothlorien","Rivendell", "Mithlond", "Lindon"), 
race = c("Maiar", "Elf", "Elf", "Elf", "Elf"))
```

So far, I have tried a tidyr::separate_rows approach

```
elvish_ring_holders %>% 
  separate_rows(name, sep = "\n\n") %>% 
  separate_rows(city, sep = "\n\n") %>% 
  separate_rows(race, sep = "\n\n") %>% 
  distinct()
```

But, I end up with a dataset where Gil-Galad and Cirdan both have two observations with two different cities with one true city and one false city.
[image]

In my exterior data, my race variable also can duplicate in this way and the data has more observations. What I am looking for is some method of separating rows that can separate once across multiple cols.

Comment: You showed your data, and the desired output. Please show the undesired output you are getting too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @GuedesBF. Implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of separating each column on it's own do them all in one go.

```
elvish_ring_holders_unclean %>% 
  separate_rows(everything(), sep = "\n\n")
```

|  | name | city | race |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Gandalf | Undying Lands | Maiar |
| 2 | Galadriel | Lothlorien | Elf |
| 3 | Elrond | Rivendell | Elf |
| 4 | Cirdan | Mithlond | Elf |
| 5 | Gil-Galad | Lindon | Elf |

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I had no idea that you could string multiple cols at once through it. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that is it. You beat me to the punch